# PDO PHP Uncaught exception

Tags: php, pdo

I have currently switched to using PDO but am having trouble in handling the exceptions. The connection is correct and queries work perfectly, but when I put in a deliberate mistake the error is not handled as I would expect.

I have changed the name of the table in my query to a table that does not exist. From the code seen below, I would expect the page to print out 'Database Error' but instead get the horrible orange error saying...

'Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.post' doesn't exist' in C:\wamp\www\website\functions.php on line 46'

Here is the code when connecting the database...

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = '';
$password = '';
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     print ("Database Error");
}
```

Am I making a mistake or is there a different way to handle PDO errors?

Comment: What happens if you just try to catch a regular `Exception` instead of the `PDOException`?

Comment: Where is the query? that's where the exception will be raised, not at the point of connection.

Comment: Are you working in a namespace? Common mistake is you need to catch `\YourException` then!

Comment: I have changed to Exception but this had no effect...I will update the code and include the query

Comment: Show the lines from C:\wamp\www\website\functions.php around line 46. My guess is that you don't try/catch there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After connecting, you need to set the error handling:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

**Edit:** Note that the exception gets caught at the place it is thrown, so you need to put a `try` `catch` block around the query, the one you use when connecting only catches exceptions there (if any, see @Crontab's comment).

Comment: Except the error is happening *when the object is created* so setting the attribute after the fact won't help anything.

Comment: I have amended the code as advised but the same error persists

Comment: @Crontab That's true of course, but that does not really apply to the OP's case where he is talking about a query.

Comment: @jeroen Ahh, I see what you mean.  He omitted the actual query part of the code and I failed to see the `test.post` in his error.  My bad.

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks very much, the tutorials I have been following only ever showed the try/catch upon connecting to the database, I therefore thought this was sufficient...thanks very much for the quick response